# quebrar data em 3 colunas numa consulta mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um sistema onde eu preciso selecionar uma data qualquer em um calendário, ai preciso retorna todos os registros do mês daquela data, por exemplo:
Tenho 4 datas, *01/08/2017*, *06/08/2017*, *14/09/2017*, *17/10/2017*. 
Suponha que eu cliquei na data "01/08/2017" e minha *query* deve retornar todas as datas registradas no mês de agosto. Nesse caso o retorno tem que ser 01/08/2017 e 06/08/2017.

Segue o código de como tentei fazer.

```
if (isset($_POST['calendar']) AND $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    $date = $_POST['date'];

    $cashier = listarColunas("cashier", " DATE_FORMAT(cas_day,'%d/%m/%Y') as 
    cas_day", "WHERE MONTH(cas_day) = '10'");
```

O campo `cas_day` é onde armazeno a data, mas eu precisava quebra-lo em 3 partes, pois dessa forma não deu certo.

Obs: Essa é minha função

```
listarColunas($tabela,  $colunas, $parametros = null)
```

Comment: Se o seu problema é buscar no MySQL o mês de uma data obtida no PHP, não seria melhor se o título refletisse isso? Pelo que entendi a necessidade de quebrar a data em 3 vem de uma tentativa de solução, não do problema em si.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se entendi bem, você quer quebrar a data em colunas para facilitar a consulta por mês?

Em vez disso você pode converter a sua string de data em data de MySQL usando `STR_TO_DATE` e comparar laranjas com laranjas na cláusula `WHERE` =)

```
$date = "01/08/2017"; //Pela pergunta esse deve ser o formato do $_POST['date']
$cashier = listarColunas("cashier", " DATE_FORMAT(cas_day,'%d/%m/%Y') as 
cas_day", "WHERE MONTH(cas_day) = MONTH(STR_TO_DATE('$date','%d/%m/%Y'))");
```

Segue um exemplo da query em si no SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e53323/8/0

Answer (score -1):

Estou considerando que seu $_POST['date'] seja uma string com uma data

```
if (isset($_POST['calendar']) AND $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

$date = new DateTime($_POST['date']);
$mes = $date->format('m');

$cashier = listarColunas("cashier", "DATE_FORMAT(cas_day,'%d/%m/%Y')", "WHERE DATE_FORMAT(cas_day,"%c") = ".$mes);
```